# iPad orientation error: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, orientation

this is my code on .m file

when i rotate orientation it waits about 7-8 seconds and gives wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 error

what did i wrong could anyone tell me?

i have 3 buttons and one background image when orientation changed the view will change
so i did this but it works very slowly

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;


UITabBarController *aaa = self.tabBarController;

NSUserDefaults *data2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([[data2 valueForKey:@"setValue"] isEqualToString:@"tr"])
{
    UITabBarItem *tabItem1 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0];
    tabItem1.title=@"Ana Ekran";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem2 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1];
    tabItem2.title=@"Mağazalar";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:2];
    tabItem3.title=@"Kampanyalar";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem4 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:3];
    tabItem4.title=@"Hesabım";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem5 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:4];
    tabItem5.title=@"İletişim";

}
else {
    UITabBarItem *tabItem1 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0];
    tabItem1.title=@"Home";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem2 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1];
    tabItem2.title=@"Stores";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:2];
    tabItem3.title=@"Promotions";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem4 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:3];
    tabItem4.title=@"Account";
    UITabBarItem *tabItem5 = [[[aaa tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:4];
    tabItem5.title=@"Contact";
}
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

[super viewDidAppear:NO];

}


 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setImgblacktie:nil];
[self setImgsarar:nil];
[self setImginterview:nil];
[self setImgbackground:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 }

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
 {
if (fromInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    NSLog(@"yatay1");
    imgbackground.frame=CGRectMake(0, -256, 1024, 1024);
    imgbackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"backgroundbuyuk.png"];

    imgblacktie.frame=CGRectMake(303, 44, 444, 173);

    imgsarar.frame=CGRectMake(303, 238, 444, 173);

    imginterview.frame=CGRectMake(303, 432, 444, 173);

}
else if(fromInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || fromInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    NSLog(@"dikey1");

    imgbackground.frame=CGRectMake(-128, 0, 1024, 1024);
    imgbackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"backgroundbuyuk.png"];

    imgblacktie.frame=CGRectMake(168, 193, 444, 173);

    imgsarar.frame=CGRectMake(168, 388, 444, 173);

    imginterview.frame=CGRectMake(168, 583, 444, 173);
}
 }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
    imgbackground.frame=CGRectMake(-128, 0, 1024, 1024);
    imgbackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"backgroundbuyuk.png"];

    imgblacktie.frame=CGRectMake(168, 193, 444, 173);

    imgsarar.frame=CGRectMake(168, 388, 444, 173);

    imginterview.frame=CGRectMake(168, 583, 444, 173);  
} 
else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {       
    imgbackground.frame=CGRectMake(0, -256, 1024, 1024);
    imgbackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"backgroundbuyuk.png"];
    imgblacktie.frame=CGRectMake(303, 44, 444, 173);

    imgsarar.frame=CGRectMake(303, 238, 444, 173);

    imginterview.frame=CGRectMake(303, 432, 444, 173);        
} 
else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {      
    imgbackground.frame=CGRectMake(0, -256, 1024, 1024);
    imgbackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"backgroundbuyuk.png"];
    imgblacktie.frame=CGRectMake(303, 44, 444, 173);

    imgsarar.frame=CGRectMake(303, 238, 444, 173);

    imginterview.frame=CGRectMake(303, 432, 444, 173); 
}
else if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    imgbackground.frame=CGRectMake(-128, 0, 1024, 1024);
    imgbackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"backgroundbuyuk.png"];

    imgblacktie.frame=CGRectMake(168, 193, 444, 173);

    imgsarar.frame=CGRectMake(168, 388, 444, 173);

    imginterview.frame=CGRectMake(168, 583, 444, 173);
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that `[super viewDidAppear:NO];` should be called at first line of `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{}` and better replace it with `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`

Comment: You should move `imgbackground.image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"backgroundbuyuk.png"];` to `-viewDidLoad` and remove it everywhere else, since it seems to be called alot for the same image...

Comment: i tried that too but it still slow :( sometimes it takes 20 seconds after i rotate to left or right

Comment: Please tell me your images are exactly 1024x1024 (or double that for retina) so the system is not resizing them in real time. Also all images (big one and overlays) should be opaque and their UIImageView have the opaque property set to YES.

Comment: now i made their opaque property set to YES. and my background image bigger than 1024 x 1024 but it was given me by designers so i cant change it now. i try to put same uiviewcontrol to another project that i recently create and it works nice. i mean it is fast when i rotate. i think it is not with images it is something in my project but what should it be? any ideas?